# Program opens cmd then closes

Tags: c#

Title says it all, it opens a command prompt then closes in 1/2 a second. i dont know why and i havent found anything on this. i just made a new c# app. Might have something to do with Main as it has no reference.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace dumb_thing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
        private void Animatetext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Animatetext.Text = "";
            Thread.Sleep(700);
            Animatetext.Text = "P";
            Thread.Sleep(350);
            Animatetext.Text = "Pa";
            Thread.Sleep(350);
            Animatetext.Text = "Par";
            Thread.Sleep(350);
            Animatetext.Text = "Para";
            Thread.Sleep(350);
            Animatetext.Text = "Parad";
            Thread.Sleep(350);
            Animatetext.Text = "Parado";
            Thread.Sleep(350);
            Animatetext.Text = "Paradox";
            Thread.Sleep(350);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me where you expect it to actually do something...the `Main` method is empty.

Comment: how would i fix this? i tried moving all the code into the main but same thing happened. i wanted it to: on load animate the text. but even when i remove everything it still opens a cmd then closes. pretty much i just want it to actually open then i can do the rest with trial and error

Comment: How did you create this class? Normally the `Main` method is defined in the `Program` class, and that's where a new instance of the `Form` is created and shown.

Comment: You used code written for a Console app in a WinForms app. Remove `static void Main(string[] args) { }` from there. `Main` is in `Program.cs`. You don't *work* there (not like that, anyway). Your code is supposed to change the text of a TextBox control. See that you have set its `Multiline` property to `true`. Or maybe you picked the wrong application template (`Windows Forms` instead of `Console`)?

Comment: You should find a C# tutorial to learn how to properly write the application, or at the very least use an IDE like Visual Studio to generate the basic shell for you.

Comment: The problem with that is i get the error "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for a entry point". i just made a empty c# application

Comment: Every C# project requires a class with a `Main` method, which is the entry point. A `WinForms` project created in `VisualStudio` will have a `Program.cs` class that defines the `Main` method, and then two `Form` partial classes that define the form's controls, methods, and events.

Comment: (sorry, I forgot to save the comment while I was away and it timed out) The `Multiline` property is irrelevant here. Just remove `static void Main`. Your TextBox control is set to change its Text when clicked. This will block the UI, since you're using `Thread.Sleep`. This blocks the whole UI Thread. You should use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` to change the Text, redefining the `Timer.Interval` value (if needed) when the `Timer.Tick` event is raised. Or add `async` to the `Click` event handler and `await Task.Delay([interval])` instead of `Thread.Sleep([interval])`.

Comment: FYI, the sample code can be simplified to: `var text = "Paradox"; Enumerable.Range(0, text.Length + 1).ToList().ForEach(i => { Animatetext.Text = text.Substring(0, i); Thread.Sleep(350); });`

Comment: @TheRacc - Please do not put "SOLVED" in your question. You should accept one of the answers to show it is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem your codes is about to run a form application. No console application.

But if you are trying to develop a console application, the console will close automatically because there is no command to make it stay or wait the next key press. So you can add a line to make the application stay before closing the `Main()` method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   //
   // your coding here
   //

   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

It is not a good practice to develop a console application via form application template. Unless to get debug output.

## Editted

If you want to develop a Form app, you have to remove the `Main` method in your form class. The `Main` method is only called once to start the form but you no need to add in your `Form` classes.

## Full Example for Form

Program.cs (Here is where the `Main` method is placed and called only once to start the other form.)

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

And now, here is the other form classes.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to includes all library needed. This example taken from VS2019 .NET Framework Form Application template.

## Other Occurs

In VS, you can set to start your project with console or not. You can set to in your `Project Properties > Application Tab > Output type` set to `Windows Application`. By default this setting will set to template setting (if form: windows application and if console: console application).

For best practice in form application, use the `debugger console` and set output using `Debug.WriteLine()`.

Comment: im not trying to make a console app, im trying to make a windows form. sorry for my little knowledge in this as im new to coding in general.

Comment: Im seeing answers about console apps, like @Mr Hery's reesponse

Comment: Thats the problem, i didnt tell it to open a cmd. i dont know why its opening a cmd. in debug it says it just exited.

Comment: Oh okay, I understood. Will update the answer. I thought you wish to create console app.

Comment: where would i remove "Main"? i cant find it in the project

Comment: See my example. Remove `static void Main(string[] args) {}` in your form class.

Comment: **SOLVED** had to wrong type of project open. had a c# app needed a windows c# form app. Thanks and sorry!

Comment: Yaa, I didnt see that coming.